# scanf lendo a variável duas vezes!

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*Faça um programa onde o usuário digita um valor, e 
imprima na tela todos os valores entre 0 e o valor digitado. */
int main()
{
    int valor, i;
    //Vamos fazer com oque o usuário digite um valor para controlar o fim do fluxo!
    printf("Informe qualquer valor diferente de 0: \n");
    scanf("%d ", &valor);
    for(i = 1; i <= valor; i++)
    {
        printf("Número: %d \n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Luis,

O problema é esse espaço que você deixou no `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d ", &valor);
```

Remova o mesmo, deixando da seguinte forma:

```
scanf("%d", &valor);
```

---

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/EasygoingBothDemand

Comment: Vou testar aqui

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, apesar de já ser tarde ter descoberto esse erro, entreguei a atividade incompleta mesmo